# Multiple extract by attribute using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, shapefile, attribute-table, extract

I am trying to extract only three polygons from my attribute table from a vector layer. The column which contains the values I want is called `"ID"`.

```py
import processing

layer = r'C:\mypath....\mylayer.shp'
output = r'C:\mypath....\out.shp'

parameters = {'INPUT': layer, 'FIELD':'ID', 'OPERATOR':'7', 'VALUE': ['08008:0:0:8:81:3' and '08008:0:0:8:81:5' and '08008:0:0:8:89:1'], 'OUTPUT': output}
feedback = QgsProcessingFeedback()

processing.runAndLoadResults('native:extractbyattribute',
                            parameters,
                            feedback=feedback
                            )
```

This code gives me a new layer with the same attribute table as the original. I know the problem is related to `'VALUE'` list, but don't know how to write the correct one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `GRASS > Vector > v.extract` tool ([see documentation](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/v.extract.html)).

```
layer = r'C:\mypath....\mylayer.shp'
output = r'C:\mypath....\out.shp'

processing.runAndLoadResults("grass7:v.extract",
                             {'input': layer,
                              'where': "ID IN (0, 1, 2, 3)", # specify IDs
                              'type': [0,1,3,4,5],
                              'output': output})
```

If field type of `ID` is string, us this for `where`:

```
'where':"ID IN ('0', '1', '2', '3')"
```

Answer (score 6):

Use extract by expression with parentheses and escape backslashes in front of each values single quote:

```
input = r'/home/bera/GIS/Data/testdata/ak_riks.shp'
output = r'/home/bera/Desktop/gistemp/ok_jl_riks_extracted.shp'

processing.run("native:extractbyexpression", 
    {'INPUT':input,
    'EXPRESSION':' "KOM_KOD" IN( \'2510\' , \'2523\' , \'2584\' )',
    'OUTPUT':output})
```

I executed the command manually then pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to see the syntax